# Regex regular expression to remove lines which start with certain text

Tags: regex, vb.net

I know it may be quite easily for you.
I have a text which contains 40 lines, I want to remove lines which starts with a constant text.
Please check below data.

When I used `(?mn)[\+CMGL:].*($)`  it removes the whole text , when I use `(?mn)[\+CMGL:].*(\r)` , it only leaves the first line.

```
+CMGL: 0,1,,159
07910201956905F0440B910201532762F20008709021225282808
+CMGL: 1,1,,159
07910201956905F0240B910201915589F7000860013222244480
+CMGL: 2,1,,151
07910201956905F0240B910201851177F6000850218122415
+CMGL: 3,1,,159
07910201956905F0440B910201532762F200087090311
+CMGL: 4,1,,159
07910221020020F0440B910221741514F40008802041120481808C050
```

I want to remove all lines that starts with +CMGL , and leave only other line.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need Regex for this? [`String.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) was created for this purpose.

```
Dim result = lines.Where(Function(l) Not l.StartsWith("+CMGL")).ToList()
```

**Edit**: If you don't have "lines" but a text which contains NewLine-characters:

```
Dim result = text.Split({ControlChars.CrLf, ControlChars.Lf}, StringSplitOptions.None).
                  Where(Function(l) Not l.StartsWith("+CMGL")).ToList()
```

If you want it to be converted back to a string:

```
Dim text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result)
```