# Remove lines starting with (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net

I have an issue where i need to remove all lines starting with the text {TAM98} from a textfile dose anybody know how to do this in VB.net?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, rewrite the file with all lines but these.

```
Dim newLines = From line In File.ReadAllLines(path)
               Where Not line.StartsWith("{TAM98}")
File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines)
```

Comment: haha I was just viewing one of your other comments Tim, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848476/regex-regular-expression-to-remove-lines-which-start-with-certain-text

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, albeit less elegant than Tim's.  Since I wrote it up already, I figured I'd post it:

```
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim myFilePath As String = "c:\MyFile.txt"
        Dim mySearchToken As String = "{TAM98}"

        For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(myFilePath)
            If (String.Compare(Left(line, mySearchToken.Length), mySearchToken, True) <> 0) Then sb.AppendLine(line)
        Next

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(myFilePath, sb.ToString())
```

Although, I will say one advantage mine has is that it doesn't matter if `TAM98` is upper or lowercase.